# how do you set cookies in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have angularjs function to translate some text. my entire controller looks like this:

```
ntsvApp.controller('ntCtrl', function($translate){
   var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.language = 'en';
    ctrl.languages = ['en', 'de'];
    ctrl.updateLanguage = function(){
        $translate.use(ctrl.language);

    };
});
```

if i put `$cookies` into updateLanguage function to be able to set cookies, angular doesn't recognize `$translate.use` method. If I place `$cookies` inside controller function, it doesn't recognize `$cookies`.put method. If i put both cookies and translate in either controller or updatelanguage nothing works. how do i make so writing cookies works only withing updatelanguage function?

Comment: try this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: tried this and tons of other sources. nothing actually helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for dependency injection,

```
ntsvApp.controller('ntCtrl', ['$translate', '$cookies', function($translate, $cookies){
   var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.language = 'en';
    ctrl.languages = ['en', 'de'];
    ctrl.updateLanguage = function(){
        $translate.use(ctrl.language);

    };
}]);
```

you can use them anywhere in the controller function now.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i got it to work with z.a. answer.

```
ntsvApp.controller('ntCtrl', ['$translate', '$cookies', function($translate, $cookies){
   var ctrl = this;
    var islang = $cookies.get('language');
    if(typeof islang != 'undefined'){
        ctrl.language = 'pl';
    }else{
     ctrl.language = $cookies.get('language'); 
    }
    ctrl.languages = ['pl', 'en'];
    ctrl.updateLanguage = function(){
        var expireDate = new Date();
        expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+1);
        $translate.use(ctrl.language);
        $cookies.put('language', ctrl.language, {'expires':expireDate});
    };
}]);
```

now i am trying to load website but it doesn't remember cookies but i guess thats another story now